# Query with 'OR' condition returns no records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to get some records from PostgreSQL DB but it returns no records when I add OR condition.

e.g.:

```
select * from table where col1 = 'A'
```

returns: 5k records

```
select * from table where col1 = 'A' and col2 <> 1
```

returns: 3k records

```
select * from table where (col1 = 'A' and col2 <> 1) or (col1 = 'B')
```

returns: 0 records

Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your final query should return at least 3k records, unless the underlying data has changed.

Comment: If you do not touched the data this behaviour is definitely not possible. Please try to reduce the problem to just a few records and show us this sample.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share example but if I change the query to 
'select * from table where (col1 = 'A' and col2 <> 1) or (col1 = 'B' and col2 <> 1)' it will return 4k records.

Comment: Your contention is basically an impossible situation. Without a [mre] there's not likely much help we can give you.